# Zip directory recursion

Tags: c++, qt, zip

I am working on creating zip archive using old `Qt` - `ZipWriter` class. The problem is when I want to add the directory. The default `Qt` code for `addDirectory` method - `d->addEntry(ZipWriterPrivate::Directory, archDirName, QByteArray());`. It does not add any content, only the empty directory. So, I have improved it to add the directories and content as well.

**My code:**

```
QList<QString> dirs;
int recursion = 0;

void ZipWriter::addDirectory(const QString &dirPath)
{
    QDir archDir(dirPath);
    archDir.setFilter(QDir::AllEntries | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);
    dirs << addDirSeparator(archDir.dirName());

    if (archDir.exists()) {
        QString archDirName = "";

        if (recursion > 0) {
            for (int i = recursion; i < dirs.count(); i++) {
                 archDirName = dirs.first().append(dirs.at(i));
            }
        } else {
            archDirName = dirs.at(recursion);
        }

        if (!archDir.isEmpty()) {
            const QStringList archFileList = archDir.entryList();

            if (archFileList.count() > 0) {
                for (QString archFile : archFileList) {
                     QFileInfo archFileInfo(QDir::toNativeSeparators(QString("%1/%2").arg(archDir.absolutePath(), archFile)));

                     if (archFileInfo.isDir()) {
                         recursion++;
                         addDirectory(archFileInfo.absoluteFilePath());
                     } else {
                         QFile zipFile(archFileInfo.absoluteFilePath());
                         zipFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
                         addFile(QString("%1%2").arg(archDirName, archFile), zipFile.readAll());
                         zipFile.close();
                     }
                }
            }
        } else {
            d->addEntry(ZipWriterPrivate::Directory, archDirName, QByteArray());
        }
    }
}
```

Now, it adds the directory and content recursively but it has issue when directory is on the same level, it appends it to the end. I think, I must use the STL container to keep track of the directory for example `QMap` but the question is how to get the current directory level? Any ideas? Thank you.

**Updated:** 01.05.2022

I have change my code to this:

```
void ZipWriter::addDirectory(const QString &dirPath)
{
    QDirIterator dirIt(dirPath, QDir::AllEntries | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
    while (dirIt.hasNext()) {
        QString archDirPath = dirIt.next();    
        QFile zipFile(archDirPath);
        zipFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

        if (!dirIt.fileInfo().isDir()) {
            addFile(archDirPath, zipFile.readAll());
        }

        zipFile.close();
    }
}
```

It adds everything recursively and in correct order but I have another issue. Now, it adds the full path to the archive. For example, I want to add this folder and it's content to the archive: `22610.1_amd64_en-us_professional_00fb7ba0_convert`.
In the archive I get: `C:\Users\userProfile\Downloads\22610.1_amd64_en-us_professional_00fb7ba0_convert`. Any ideas how to make this relative path or trim it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `QDirIterator` to recursively iterate over directory and subdirectories, and I believe you dont need to add nonempty directories at all, just files will be fine.

And why would you use stl container in qt, please use qt containers.

Comment: Ok. I will try `QDirIterator`. I need to have directories as well, otherwise all files from different directories will be in the same folder. So, I need to keep the content tree order. Also, in this case, I will use Qt containers. Thanks.

Comment: no they wont be in the same folder if you provide correct relative path (with slashes)

Comment: I have tried your solution. It works well but it adds the full path to the archive. Please check out my updated post. Thanks.

Comment: addFile(QDir(dirPath).relativeFilePath(archDirPath), zipFile.readAll());